# chrome developer tools not working on specific website

Tags: google-chrome

I am building a website - currently its on http://samgalconcept.co.il/en/
The problem is - when I click on "inspect element" and change website's functionality I don't see the changes.
Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: most things are changing but some aren't because they are hidden and items similar to them are there but they are pictures of text and unselectable.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Hi and thanks, Im trying to change to menu ul and li css properties, its seems that nothing happends